# How to download FTP file using its full FTP path?

Tags: python, file-io, ftp, ftplib

Using the ftplib in Python, you can download files, but it seems you are restricted to use  the file name only (not the full file path). The following code successfully downloads the requested code:

```
import ftplib
ftp=ftplib.FTP("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov")
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd("/allData/5/MOD11A1/2002/001")
ftp.retrbinary('RETR MOD11A1.A2002001.h00v08.005.2007079015634.hdf',open("MOD11A1.A2002001.h00v08.005.2007079015634.hdf",'wb').write)
```

As you can see, first a login to the site (`ftp.login()`) is established and then the current directory is set (`ftp.cwd()`). After that you need to declare the file name to download the file that resides in the current directory.
How about downloading the file directly by using its full path/link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov")
ftp.login()

a = 'allData/5/MOD11A1/2002/001/MOD11A1.A2002001.h00v08.005.2007079015634.hdf'
fhandle = open('ftp-test', 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + a, fhandle.write)
fhandle.close()
```

Comment: It works, and it is around 1 second faster then when setting the current directory.

Comment: But when I input variable a instead of "ftp-test', it does not work.

Comment: +1 on that. @ArditSulce check what you are sending using `type(your_variable)`

Comment: @Jacek and mislav: Nope, it does not work, neither with Python 2, nor with 3. Just try to replace 'ftp-test' with a and you will believe me.

Comment: well you can not write to a directory that does not exist on your disk. first you would have to create the needed dir structure. use pythons `os.path.exists` + `os.makedirs`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the urlopen function in the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) module. The urlopen function will let you download ftp and http urls. I like using it because you can connect and get all the data in one line. The last three lines extract the filename from the url and then save the data to that filename.

```
from urllib import urlopen
url = 'ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/2002/001/MOD11A1.A2002001.h00v08.005.2007079015634.hdf'
data = urlopen(url).read()
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```